# Antenna gain improvement by increasing directivity but not with radiation efficiency

Tags: antenna

My antenna gain got increased with directivity but not with radiation efficiency. I mean the radiation efficiency remained same. Speaking of remaining radiation efficiency, this improvement on the gain will not mean that antenna will transmit its power at longer distance than it used to. Can we call it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if the efficiency remained the same and the gain/directivity improved, then you can use this antenna for longer distance transmission than before.

Comment: @Burak Aktas But getting an antenna with higher directivity cannot always be fully utilized for longer communication distance. Radio transmission codes in many countries order to decrease the transmitting power in the same proportion as antenna gain exceeds 0dB. The gain increase affects also in the receiving end. Weaker transmitters become detectable. It's is NOT easy to explain plausibly how this works especially if the antenna with higher directivity isn't substantially bigger.